# How to exclude certain properties when validating model with TryValidateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 project and need to exclude certain properties from server side validation. I am looking for something like in this question [Is it possible to override the required attribute on a property in a model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903838/is-it-possible-to-override-the-required-attribute-on-a-property-in-a-model-asp) but I do not want to bind the model again because I have already made changes to it (from my understanding that is what TryUpdateModel will do).

From related question

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
 var model = new BaseModel();

 if (TryUpdateModel(model, null, null, new[] { "RequiredProperty" })) // fourth parameter is an array of properties (by name) that are excluded
 {
      // updated and validated correctly!
      return View(model);
 }
 // failed validation
 return View(model);
}
```

I want to validate the already updated model excluding certain properties. Should I just use TryUpdateModel like hackedbychinese suggested in the linked question? Could it change the values of the properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the jquery validation rules remove method.

```
$("#fax_DisplayPhoneNumber").rules("remove", "required");
```

This overrides the `[Required]` tag on the fax `DisplayPhoneNumber` property in the model so it is no longer a required input.