# How can I disable required attribute on a property in a model in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, modelmetadata

How to disable the `[Required]` attribute that has been set on a model property.

I tried with below code using `new` keyword but not working.

I also tried `override` keyword as well not worked.

`ChildModel` uses most of the properties of `BaseModel` that's instead of create new model file and code many similar properties I'm thinking to do something like this.

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Address{ get; set; }
}


public class ChildModel : BaseModel
{
    public new string Address{ get; set; }    
}
```

Any simple solution ?

Comment: This previous question should help you out: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903838/is-it-possible-to-override-the-required-attribute-on-a-property-in-a-model?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903838/is-it-possible-to-override-the-required-attribute-on-a-property-in-a-model?rq=1)

Comment: I tried but its not working :( base and derived solution.
what is this `[MetadataType(typeof(Base.Metadata))]` ? any comment?

Comment: Have you tried @Saito's answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903838/is-it-possible-to-override-the-required-attribute-on-a-property-in-a-model?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903838/is-it-possible-to-override-the-required-attribute-on-a-property-in-a-model?rq=1) This works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply overriding or redeclaring using the `new` keyword on the property and removing the attribute does not work. The way I have always done this is like below.:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public abstract string Address { get; set; }
}


public class ChildModel : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public override string Address { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherChildModel : BaseModel
{
    //Not[Required]
    public override string Address { get; set; }
}
```

You can read [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff0a549d-7d79-44eb-af6f-36526badd8c9/attributes-and-inheritance-on-fieldspropertiesmethods?forum=netfxbcl) thread if you want to know more on how attributes of a base class are treated during inheritance.